# Conditionally assign a value to variable in .yml file

Tags: jenkins, ansible, yaml

I have a text file and a yml file
the text file has a variable

```
is_true = true
```

And the .yml file has another variable my_value which I want to assign it a value based on is_true condition
I have tried many solutions online but none of them works
For example

Example #1:

```
{% if is_true == true %}
  my_value:'A'
{% elif is_true == false %}
  my_value:'B'
{% endif %}
```

Example #2

```
my_value: $[if(is_true, 'A', 'B')]
```

I did try other examples as well but I wasn't able to properly set the value.
I am not sure if this is a syntax issue or not.

BTW I do not want to write an ansible task to do this,  just a yml file in which I am trying to set a value to a variable

Comment: You tagged this question with both Ansible and Jenkins, where are you trying to do this? In a playbook? In a Jenkinsfile? Else?

Comment: If this is in Ansible, use the inline-if of Jinja: `my_value: "{{ 'A' if is_true else 'B' }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **ternary** filter:

```
- set_fact:
    my_value: "{{ (is_true == true) | ternary ('positive', 'negative') }}"
  when: is_true is defined
```

If the condition in parentheses is true the first value is assigned to **my_value** i.e. 'positive' - else if the condition is false the second value i.e. 'negative'

The **when** statement covers the case of **is_true** setting missing from your config.